# Xampp SSL - Server's certificate does not match the url and not trusted

Tags: apache, ssl, https, xampp

I have created and activated an SSL certificate in Xampp by:

1. Create a **`cert`** folder in **`D:\xampp\apache\`**
2. Download **`cert-template.conf`** and **`make-cert.bat`** on the internet.
3. Copy the two files into the **`cert`** folder.
4. Change the contents of **`commonName_default`** and **`DNS.1`** to **`localhost`** in the **`cert-template.conf`** file.
5. Run the **`make-cert.bat`** file -> Output: **`localhost`** folder, **`server.key`** file and **`server.crt`** file in the **`localhost`** folder.
6. Install **`server.crt`** and save in **`Local Machine -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities`**
7. Added the line **`127.0.0.1 localhost`** in the **`hosts`** file.
8. Add this configuration in **`httpd-vhosts.conf`** file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    ServerName localhost
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L] 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "cert/localhost/server.crt" 
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "cert/localhost/server.key"
    <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

9. Add this configuration in **`http-xampp.conf`** file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    
    # Redirect /xampp folder to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} xampp
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

    # Redirect /phpMyAdmin folder to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} phpmyadmin
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

    # Redirect /security folder to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} security
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

    # Redirect /webalizer folder to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} webalizer
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]
    
    # Redirect /mercenaries folder to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} mercenaries
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

10. Restarting apache via xampp control panel (as administrator).
11. (There may be another step I forgot.)

After doing the steps above, when I opened **`localhost`** via chrome on a PC with Xampp installed, the site switched to using https and **`localhost`** was declared secure. Yeayy..

However, the problem is that when I open localhost using IP 192.168.75.74 via chrome on my cellphone, the address is not safe:

```
The identity of this website isn't verified.
• Server's certificate does not match the URL.
• Server's certificate is not trusted.
```

[image: Web Not Secure]

Maybe because the domain I entered is **`localhost`** so it doesn't match if I enter the IP address on my cellphone.

Just for information, I connected my phone to my PC using USB tethering. However, I have also tried connecting the PC to the Access Point device via LAN cable and the cellphone via WiFi and the results are the same.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: In short: the subject(s) of the certificate must match the URL. If you want to use `https://192.168.75.74` to access the server then you need to have a subject alternative name of type IP and value 192.168.75.74 in your certificate.

Comment: I think I've tried this before, but it hasn't worked. Maybe there are steps that I missed, well... I'll try again.

Comment: Based on your description step 4 you have only `localhost` in the certificate as SAN, nothing else.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I added `DNS.1 = localhost`
`DNS.2 = *.localhost`
`IP.1 = 192.168.75.74`
`IP.2 = 127.0.0.1` in 'cert-template' and when I open `localhost` or `192.168.75.74` on the PC it works and is declared safe, but on my phone there is still 1 problem left which is `Server's certificate is not trusted`. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: For a certificate to be trusted the issuer CA also needs to be trusted. Maybe this is the problem you have on the phone.

Comment: I tried installing the certificate onto my Android phone, but the site was still declared unsafe. `Your connection to 192.168.75.74 is encrypted using modern cipher suite. Further, this page includes other resources which are not secure. These resources......`. Before I bought a real domain and SSL, I wanted to use this offline site to develop my Android application, but it seems that's all there is to it for security. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Uppss.. sorry, looks like it worked.. Previously I didn't close chrome first but after I closed chrome then opened it again on my cellphone.. and finally my site was declared safe.. hahaha.